# How do I reference a static method of a variable class in PHP?

Tags: php, static, reference, variables, methods

I'm writing a factory class that should be able to return singleton instances of a number of different types, depending on the given parameter. The method would look something like this, but the way I'm referencing the singleton's static method is obviously wrong:

```
public function getService($singletonClassName) {
    return $singletonClassName::getInstance();
}
```

What would the correct syntax for such a reference look like in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use that kind of syntax with PHP < 5.3 : it's one of the new features of PHP 5.3

A couple of possibilities, with PHP 5.2, would be to :

- use the name of the class, if you know it
- Or use something like [`call_user_func`](https://www.php.net/call_user_func)

In the first case, it would be as simple as :

```
ClassName::getInstance()
```

And, in the second, you'd use something like :

```
call_user_func($singletonClassName .'::getInstance');
```

*According to the documentation of [`call_user_func`](https://www.php.net/call_user_func), this should work with PHP >= 5.2.3*

Or you could just use :

```
call_user_func(array($singletonClassName, 'getInstance'));
```

Comment: *cough* Five *cough* minutes :)

Comment: When I started writting my answer, yours was not as complete as it is now ^^ *(There was only the first portion of the answer, with the name of the class hard-coded) -- and we both edited a couple of times ^^ *

Comment: Actually, I learned the shoot-early-then-add-stuff trick from you. Noticed you do do this several times and found it very cunning :)

Comment: I learnt that from others, too ^^ ;; I generally consider that a basic *(but quick)* answer can help, if the guy who asked searches a bit more by himself ;; and if he waits a bit more or doesn't understand the basic answer, there will be a better one a couple of minutes after ;;; and I sometimes do this for answer that have been accepted, too, just so the accepted answer is better, and can help people reading it later *(when coming via google, for example)*.

Comment: Well, many thanks to the both of you, anyway :) As to which answer I should tag as accepted, I'll have to flip a coin.

Comment: @Johan : you're welcome :-) *(and for the "flip a coin" part, I have to admit that I smiled ^^ )*

Comment: @Johan I am young and need the reputation ;) J/K, go flip the coin.

Comment: /me *starts sobbing* ;) I guess that's c'est la vie

Answer (score 0):

You just use the class name

```
public function getService($singletonClassName) {
    return SingletonClassName::getInstance();
}
```

Alternatively, if `$singleClassName` is a variable containing the classname use

```
public function getService($singletonClassName) {
    return call_user_func( array($singletonClassName, 'getInstance') );
}
```

As of 5.2.3 you can also do

```
call_user_func($singletonClassName .'::getInstance'); // As of 5.2.3
```